# How can I set border-opacity for IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, opacity

The following code works for chrome and firefox, however it doesn't work in IE.

```
border: 2px solid rgb(191, 191, 191, .25);
```

How can I mimic this effect for IE?

Comment: Did you try using rgba instead of rgb?

Comment: for you opacity you must use `a` rgba

Comment: Just tried this and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: If so, please self-answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rgba` instead of `rgb`

```
border: 2px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, .25);
```

Answer (score 0):

missing alpha channel

```
border:2px solid rgba(191, 191, 191, .25)
```